# Enable mtrace (MALLOC_TRACE) for binary program

Tags: malloc, glibc, mtrace

How can I enable [`mtrace()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/mtrace.3.html)  (and `MALLOC_TRACE` env) for a binary program without sources?

mtrace is feature of glibc: http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Allocation-Debugging.html

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

mtrace.c

```
#include <mcheck.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void __mtracer_on () __attribute__((constructor));
void __mtracer_off () __attribute__((destructor));
void __mtracer_on ()
{
    char *p=getenv("MALLOC_TRACE");
    char tracebuf[1023];
    if(!p)
        p="malloc_trace";
    sprintf(tracebuf, "%s.%d", p, getpid());
    setenv("MALLOC_TRACE",tracebuf, 1);
    atexit(&__mtracer_off);
    mtrace();
}

void __mtracer_off ()
{
    muntrace();
}
```

Compile with `gcc mtrace.c  -fPIC -shared  -o libmmtrace.so`

Run with

```
MALLOC_TRACE=echo LD_PRELOAD=./libmmtrace.so /bin/echo 42
```

or

```
LD_PRELOAD=./libmmtrace.so /bin/echo 42
```

Is it ok for you?